# Why did "Ubuntu software Center turned into grey one?

Tags: software-center, crash

As you can see my Ubuntu Software Center is grey.I want to know why did it happen? Is my system gonna crash?

[image]

Comment: system ? probably not. Software Center ? probably. Usually let the software center finish what it's doing. Otherwise if it's been like that for 20 mins, kill the window

Comment: What does the `opera` tag has to do with it??

Comment: sorry, guys I'm a newbie.

Comment: @Serg Software center is same. You said, "kill the window" does it mean I've to shut down the machine?

Comment: @SayanLaha nope, no need to shutdown machine. Just stop the app. Open terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and type in `xkill` . Your mouse pointer will change to "x" and you can select the software center to close immediately

Comment: @Serg I did as you said. Do I need to restart it? If yes, then is there any chance of GRUB problem?

Comment: I told you several times already - no, you don't need to restart the machine . GRUB and Software Center are not related.  If there's any problem system will report it. Don't worry that much, it's just an app that got stuck, that's all

Comment: @Serg, thanks for the help. I'm sending you an email, if you have some time... please check it.

Comment: @Serg, well... GRUB is not related to an app. but upgrades of the kernel will require an update to the GRUB files... Although on my end I did not have any problem with GRUB in ages.

Comment: @AlexisWilke once new kernel is installed, GRUB only needs to update the default entry. GRUB doesn't deal with software installation whatsoever. It's the same as if i were to install manually from deb or source. So it's only tangentially related. Average user doesn't need to care about this

Answer (score 2):

When an X11 application is not responsive (does not wait for messages on the X11 pipe) the system shows the corresponding window in gray like that.

The reason is generally because the application is doing some work for a while, a while considered too long by X11.

In this case it is probably gathering the data from the set of installed files and that is many files and can be slow. After a few seconds it should wake up though. If not, check the disk activity. As long as the disk is busy, I wouldn't worry about it. If the disk activity stops and the screen stay gray for more than 10 seconds, it's probably dead (something broken in the application but it did not quit so the window stays up but it is not usable.)

As a side note, this happens to me with my mail system because once in a while it takes too long connecting and downloading emails. It can happen with my browser because a JavaScript is too slow and blocks the whole application...

Comment: Can you tell me how to look for "disk activity"? It's stuck there for more than 20 mins, so I'm kinda worried.

Comment: 20 min. sounds like a long time even for that software. On my computer I have 4 LEDs on the front panel and one of them shows the hard drive activity. Usually, the orange one. It varies somewhat between computers. I have computers that have one for network activity and usually one to let you know whether the computer is ON or not.

Comment: If it is "that bad", you may just want to kill the process and restart it. If you click on the close button, it should ask you whether you want to kill that process. Just say yes and wait a little bit (maybe 1 min.) and try to restart. The wait is to make sure it quit completely before you restart. (a kill is normally an instant kill, but I have had problems)